# MATLAB. How can we get a 2d multinomial by interpolation

Tags: matlab, 2d, multinomial

We are given a n x n data. Approximate the funxtion.
For example. If we are given 2(1,1), 3(1,2), 4(2,1), 5(2,2)
Then we have to interpolate the 2 D- ultinomial as $0*x*y+y+2*x-1$.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be formulated as a set of linear equations, which are trivial to solve using [mldivide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) function.

Let me illustrate this using the example you included.

```
% from the given example 
in = [...
    1,1;
    1,2;
    2,1;
    2,2];

out = [...
    2;
    3;
    4;
    5];

% compute the variable terms in the polynomial
x  = in(:,1);
y  = in(:,2);
xy = x .* y;
c  = ones(size(out)); % constant

% compute the coefficients of the polynomial 
p = [xy,y,x,c] \ out; 
% result: [0; 1; 2; -1]
```

The statement`p = [xy,y,x,c] \ out` computes the optimal coefficients (least-square error) when the problem is overconstrained (i.e. no solution exists to **exactly** satisfy all equations). But if there are only as many equations as there are variables (like in this example, there are 4 equations due to 4 input-output pairs and there are 4 coefficients that need to be estimated), then the coefficients can be computed simply by `p = inv([xy,y,x,c]) * out`.